# windows tensorflow hub saver not created error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

My code as below

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)

x = ["Roasted ants are a popular snack"]

# Extract ELMo features 
#embeddings = elmo(x, signature="default", as_dict=True)["elmo"]

#embeddings.shape



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    abc=sess.run(elmo(x, signature="default", as_dict=True)["elmo"])
```

I am getting the below message. What am i doing wrong? how could i get rid of it?

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
```

My package versions below

```
print (tf.__version__)
1.15.0-rc3

print (hub.__version__)
0.6.0


C:\Users\nnn>python -V
Python 3.7.3
```

Answer (score 1):

That logging message is safe to ignore (but hard to get rid of). It comes up due to the way how hub.Module calls tf.train.import_meta_graph but handles restoring variables by itself.